# error: no matching function for call to, when using C++. Though include the related method in the head file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run the code from https://github.com/encryptogroup/PSI.git,
when I generate .o files with the command of gcc -c *.cpp, it gave me the following error:

`./crypto/crypto.h:165:2: error: no matching function for call to 'readCodeWords'
        readCodeWords(*codewords);`

In crypto.h, the related code is

```
static void InitAndReadCodeWord(REGISTER_SIZE*** codewords) {
uint32_t ncodewords = m_nCodeWordBits;
uint32_t ncwintlen = 8;
*codewords = (REGISTER_SIZE**) malloc(sizeof(REGISTER_SIZE*) * ncodewords);
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < ncodewords; i++) {
    (*codewords)[i] = (REGISTER_SIZE*) malloc(sizeof(REGISTER_SIZE) * ((ncwintlen * sizeof(uint32_t)) / sizeof(REGISTER_SIZE)));
}
readCodeWords(*codewords);}
```

The readCodeWords() is defined in codewords.h,
but I already include it in crypto.h,
the error remains still.

Comment: And the prototype for `readCodeWords` is?

Comment: A quick glance suggests that it's a combination of a failed attempt at platform independence (afaict, that function will only compile on platforms where an `unsigned long int` is 64 bits wide) and failure to follow given instructions (you should use `make`, not handcrafted command lines).

Answer (score 2):

Check if the variable that you're using as the argument can be accepted by the funcion parameter.

I'm not sure what REGISTER_SIZE is and I'm unable to test it at the moment, but the include and functions seems fine, maybe the type is not.

## Udpate

I was able to check your code, and the function takes a uint64_t, `static void readCodeWords(uint64_t** codewords)` and REGISTER_SIZE evaluates to either `uint32_t` or `unsigned long int` or `uint16_t`, depending on the system.

```
#define MAX_INT (~0)
#if (MAX_INT == 0xFFFFFFFF)
#define MACHINE_SIZE_32
typedef uint32_t REGISTER_SIZE;

#elif (MAX_INT == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#define MACHINE_SIZE_64
typedef unsigned long int REGISTER_SIZE;

#else
#define MACHINE_SIZE_16
typedef uint16_t REGISTER_SIZE;

#endif
```

I might just be an incompatibility with the parameter of the function.